# Chrome Extension Dev. - Display thumbnail of webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Am trying to display a custom new tab page by creating a Chrome Extension. Everything works fine except one part. That is, I want to display the thumbnail of a webpage (top visited site). I was able to get the top visited website and url.

But when I try to access the thumbnail of that website like this:

```
<img src="chrome://thumb/https://stackoverflow.com/" />
```

it gives an error message in Console window saying:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   chrome://thumb/https://stackoverflow.com/

In my extension's manifest file, I have already included the following permission: `"chrome://thumb"` as I found this in a website where a person posted a similar question (created in 2013 or something)

But when I checked the docs for permissions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions , I don't see that permission though.

So what would be the workaround to display the thumbnail?

Comment: try permission "chrome://thumb/*" or "chrome://favicon/"

Comment: @TomBerghuis, nope it didn't worked. Tried both.

Comment: try adding permision "<all_urls>"

Comment: @TomBerghuis, nope. No luck either.

Comment: As you can see, it's not possible.